# Making something happen when something is selected in a UIPickerView

Tags: objective-c, uipickerview

I was working on creating an app that uses a UIPickerView. I made the view but I am trying to make a certain button change what it does. Please help.

Comment: Update your question with relevant code and explain what you want to do differently.

Comment: Do you know how to use delegates?

Answer (score 0):

UIPickerView and many other controls use delegate pattern to inform you about events happening.
To use it add `<UIPickerViewDelegate>` to your class type definition(@interface line) and after that set the delegate of UIPickerView to your class like this:

```
myUIPickerView.delegate = self;
```

Then you can write the following [method](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIPickerViewDelegate/pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:) in your class and `row` is the index you want:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
      didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row
       inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    switch(row)
    {
         //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Im still confused on what to put instead of "row". Should I just put whatever I named it in my UIPickerView. Also I have two statements that say what you wrote up there. One changes a label text and the other does something else. Is there any way to have both My plan was to change what a particular button does when something in the UIPickerView is pressed. How would I do that. Thanks and I look forward to your response.

Comment: @EliasTurk Again, update your question with relevant code so we can see what you have. This will make it much easier to give you a useful answer.

Comment: @rmaddy I am going to post a new question called. Using a UIPickerView and changing what a button does. I will add the code so that you can see.

Comment: @EliasTurk No, don't post a new question. Update this one.

Comment: @EliasTurk row is an integer and the index of the item selected in UIPickerView. What are you confused on?